# Limit of a recursive function

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, computer-science

I have a recursive functoin:

$$\log^{'}(n) = \begin{cases} & 1 \text{ if } n \leqslant 1 \\ & 1 + log^{'}(\log(n))\text{ otherwise}  \end{cases}$$

This function grows VERY slowly. Is this function limited? 
How do I compare: $$n^2 \;\;\text{and}\;\;\; 2^{\log^{'}(n)}$$
Is it true that $n^2$ grows slower than $2^{\log^{'}(n)}$  for $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: It's inverse Ackermann function. It grows as O(1)

Answer (score 1):

Compare the order of the functions you have, set $\log n =t$ and $\log t =v$ and take the limit of the ratio. What do you get?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the question. I fixed it.

Comment: so you want to know what happens to the ration of these two functions as $n \to \infty$? Can you extend the idea I gave you to the next step?

Comment: I want to know what function grows faster: $2^{log^{'}(n)}\; or\; n^2\;for\;n\rightarrow inf $. Do you have idea?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my question again.

Comment: pls see the edit